# Aspect not getting called in Spring

Tags: java, spring

When save method of MyBean is called aspect not getting called

MyBean.java

```
package com.crm.web.beans;
public class MyBean {
   public String save() {
       System.out.pringln("Save is called");
   }
}
```

AppConfig.java

```
@Configuration
@EnableAspectJAutoProxy
public class AppConfig {

@Bean
  public MyLogger myAspect() {
    return new MyLogger();
}

}
```

MyLogger.java

```
@Configuration
@Aspect
public class MyLogger {
private Logger log = Logger.getAnonymousLogger();


@Around("execution(* com.crm.web.beans.*(..))")
public void log(JoinPoint point) {
    System.out.println("This is calledddddddddd");

    log.info(point.getSignature().getName() + " called...");
}
```

}

applicationcontext.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"

xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.0.xsd ">

<context:annotation-config />
<context:spring-configured />

</beans>
```

Iam calling save method only "Save is called " gets printed.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you have compile time or runtime weaving enabled?

Comment: Post the code that's calling `save`. Self-call until proven innocent.

Comment: public void save() {
  if (context != null) {
   MyBean mybean= new MyBean();
   mybean.save();
  }

 }

Comment: Should not MyBean be a managed bean too?

Comment: I tried using ManagedBean of jsf even its not getting called

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok I think I made it work, try this:

```
@Configuration
@EnableAspectJAutoProxy
public class AppConfig {

@Bean
  public MyLogger myAspect() {
    return new MyLogger();
}

@Bean
  public MyBean myBean() {
    System.out.println("MyBean is called");
    return new MyBean();
}

}
```

And then:

```
public class MainApp {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ApplicationContext context = 
          new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(AppConfig.class);
        MyBean mybean = context.getBean(MyBean.class);
        mybean.save();
    }

}
```

This way you might get a 'unresolvable circular reference' error, I think it is because it is trying to log the logger class. You can fix it changing your Around expression, withc lack an '*' anyway, to something like this:

```
@Around("execution(* com.crm.web.beans.MyBean.*(..))")
```

Check also the answers from flob and JavaBond.

Answer (score 3):

Your pointcut expression isn't correct. It should be something like below

```
@Around("execution(* com.crm.web.beans..(..))")
```

See reference docs [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/aop.html#aop-pointcuts-examples) *(refer point - the execution of any method defined in the service package)*

Also correct the `@Configuration` annotation to `@Component` on `MyLogger` as below

```
@Component
@Aspect
public class MyLogger { .. }
```

See explanation [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/aop.html#aop-at-aspectj). Pasting the relevant part below.

*You may register aspect classes as regular beans in your Spring XML configuration, or autodetect them through classpath scanning - just like any other Spring-managed bean. However, note that the @Aspect annotation is not sufficient for autodetection in the classpath: For that purpose, you need to add a separate **@Component** annotation (or alternatively a custom stereotype annotation that qualifies, as per the rules of Spring’s component scanner).*

Comment: -I tried this but this but still log method dosent get called

Comment: -thanks for your help.I got error when using @Around("execution(* com.crm.web.beans..(..))").'name pattern cannot finish with .. Instead i used @Around("execution(* com.crm.web.beans..*(..))").  Your post helped me a lot

Comment: glad i could be of help :)

Comment: @Bond-JavaBond Trying to understand why you need both annotation.. is this because @ Aspect is AspectJ specific and not Spring specific ? And in order to make Spring aware of it you have to add the @ Component ?

Comment: @Victor   `@EnableAspectJAutoProxy` applies to its local application context only, allowing for selective proxying of beans at different levels. So there must be a way to introduce them to the context you are applying them  to with `@ComponentScan` or `@Component` atleast in this case. Check here for more https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/EnableAspectJAutoProxy.html

Answer (score 0):

You are either

- missing 
  the two AspectJ libraries on the classpath of your application: `aspectjweaver.jar` and `aspectjrt.jar`  (@see  [Spring Aspectj documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.x/reference/aop.html#aop-aspectj-support) ) or
- you are not calling the enhanced proxy but within `MyBean` itself.